# Strange SQL problem selecting multiple values for same column

Tags: mysql

Been at this for a few hours now and I can't make any sense of it. I've used this way of selecting multiple values for same column a few times, but there is something weird with this one.

```
SELECT * FROM employee as s
INNER JOIN works AS w1 ON w1.name = s.name
INNER JOIN employee AS w2 ON w2.name = s.name
INNER JOIN employee AS w3 ON w3.name = s.name
WHERE w2.city = 'Washington'
```

Basically what I want to do is find all companies which have people in all the cities. The company name is under 'works'. The problem is however that if I have the WHERE w2.city='Washington' it will make ALL the cities match Washington when it should only touch w2 and leave w3 alone so I could match it with another value.

Anyone know why its doing this? Or know a better way to do it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: can you explain why 'INNER JOIN employee AS w2 ON w2.name = s.name' bit is repeated?

Comment: So that there will be enough city columns to match up with different values.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE:

Okay, I think I understand now what you're trying to do.

EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT s.* FROM Employee AS s
INNER JOIN Works AS w1 ON w1.Name = s.Name
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT e1.Name FROM Employee AS e1 WHERE e1.City = 'Washington'
    UNION
    SELECT e2.Name FROM Employee AS e2 WHERE e2.City = 'Atlanta'
) AS sub ON sub.Name = s.Name
```

---

### ORIGINAL:

I'm assuming you're doing this repeated join to ultimately have multiple search criteria on the same column? Maybe you simplified the SQL for demonstration purposes but as it stands now i don't see the limitation that would require you to do the multiple join.

Perhaps simplifying your statement might work with the addition of a WHERE IN function.

EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee AS s
INNER JOIN Works AS w1 ON w1.Name = s.Name
WHERE s.City IN ('Washington', 'Atlanta')
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but WHERE s.city IN works as a OR for the values, while I need it to knock down the companies which doesn't have all the cities represented.